# How to \import* without breaking other packages?

Tags: packages, import

I am struggling to set up the package [*import*](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/import?lang=en) properly.
Here is what I am doing:

The main file includes another file with a very common name.
To make sure that the correct file is loaded, I use *\import** instead of *\import*.

For some reason this breaks the functionality of *amsfonts*.
I get the warnings shown below and the output file just contains a plain *a*.

Can anyone help me out?

> ./main.tex

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
  \import*{./}{generic_name.tex}
\end{document}
```

> ./generic_name.tex

```tex
$\mathfrak{a}$
```

> Warnings

```
(./generic_name.tex

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/msa/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `U/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 1.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/msb/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `U/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 1.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/euf/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `U/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 1.

) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 )</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
```

Comment: import generally causes more problems than it solves, it is not at all clear why you can not go `\input{./generic name}` it will get the one from the current directory which seems to be exactly what you want `\import` to do.

Comment: I just switched from `\input` to `\import`. So I can't yet tell if your general rule applies to my case.
My real document is split into files `./main.tex`, `./chapterN/main.tex`, `./chapterN/img/` etc.
Some images are TeX-files (they use `\includegraphics`, but do not know about the document structure).
This is why I had to provisionally add `./chapterN/img/` to `TEXINPUTS` for each chapter.
With `\import` I no longer need to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is due to LaTeX's delayed method of handling math fonts. Thus, the use of `\mathfrak` inside `generic_name.tex` triggers an input of `ueuf.fd` (and other font definition files). But the `import` package forces imported files to look for their input files in that given directory, where `ueuf.fd` does not exist.

I don't see a complete solution without a rewrite of `import.sty` (or maybe `amsfonts.sty`), but this particular problem can be worked around by putting the following in the preamble, probably after `\usepackage{amsfonts}`:

```
\input{ueuf.fd}
\input{umsa.fd}
\input{umsb.fd}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! This workaround solves the problem.